# Visual Studio 2012 build application for windows 10?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Will it be compatibility issue If I build application in `Windows 7` with `Visual Studio 2012`, and the application will run on `Windows 10`?

Comment: All windows are backward compatible. Unless you're using some very special feature, why care about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 10 will run applications built for windows 7.

Comment: oh, what minimum vs should i use if need to build for win 10 ?

Comment: youcan use vs2012 for,  however ,if you want to make "universal apps" which win 10 can run, then you should use vs2015.....  but if you have the option, you can get vs2015 anyways ( its free ).  You can write applications that run on win7 as well as the latest win10

Comment: but I cannot install vs2015 with win7, i think the solution will be install windows 10 only :( .

Comment: you can upgrade to win10?  you can still develop for win7 with vs2015 though

Comment: @mysticcode What do you mean you can't install VS2015 on windows 7 I have been running it on Windows 7 since beta.

Comment: @MarkHall , it pops up need to have newer operating system